# How to know query execution time without running query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

**Goal -->** Try to find the execution time the query will take to display result before executing the query.

**Detail Description -->** 
I am trying to run an simple query , for Example one shown below,
I am trying to find out how much actual time the query will take before running the query

```
SELECT top 1 *
FROM table_name
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way/tool to identify estimate query run time in SQL sERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469918/is-there-any-way-tool-to-identify-estimate-query-run-time-in-sql-server)

Comment: Logically, since there are so many different factors that would affect query time (processor, memory, connection speeds, indexes, statistics, cache, etc), that'd be hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

The answer isn't fixed.  You can run the query, have it take 5 seconds, repeat it and have it take less than one because some part of the query or results were cached.

Contention on tables makes a difference too.  Selecting has to wait if it uses an index that's being updated.

All you can do is experiment to make estimates, potentially also using control L to get an estimated execution plan.